# Installed Ubuntu with the wubi installer, but can't find it.

Tags: installation, wubi

I did an install of Ubuntu on my windows using the Wubi installer, but was unable to locate it on my pc.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've installed Ubuntu using the [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) installer, just reboot--then you'll get a screen to choose whether to run Ubuntu or Windows. (You'll get this choice every time.)